# How can I start my virtualbox instance with the same state?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is it possible to save a state of a vm in virtualbox, and from then always restart this vm by restoring the state ?

My problem, is that the state is deleted after restoration, and I can't restore it a second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VirtualBox, there is a feature called Snapshot, which allows you to take a snapshot of the current state of the VM.

You can take a snapshot by going to `Machine -> Take Snapshot (Host + T)` while the VM is running.

If the VM is suspended (machine state saved), you could go to the `Snapshots` tab to take a snapshot.

From the Snapshots tab, one could also boot up a particular snapshot of the VM.

Comment: Is the snapshot also for the memory state ? I thought that the snapshot was only for the hard drive state.

Comment: The [VirtualBox docs](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#idp56573712) states: Finally, if you took a snapshot while the machine was running, the memory state of the machine is also saved in the snapshot (the same way the memory can be saved when you close the VM window). When you restore such a snapshot, execution resumes at exactly the point when the snapshot was taken.